# something's wrong with the css path in my haml file

Tags: css, ruby, path, sinatra, haml

The directory structure is as follows:

```
approot
` public
  ` css
    - main.css
` views
  - home.haml
  - index.haml
- main.rb
```

and I've tried to call my css in the haml file with:

`%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => url('css/main.css')}`,

`%link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css")`

and
`%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => "css/main.css"}`

Nothing works by far. I'm using sinatra if that matters.

Comment: How does the generated HTML file look like?

Comment: !!!
%html
  %head
    %title This is the Title
    %link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css")
  %body
    ...

Comment: After HAML has created the file! something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">`

Comment: You can open this page in your browser, can't you? Then right click and choose "Show Source". That is your HTML page.

Comment: Yes. Or you can just F12 it. All looks just fine in the HTML. Other CSS links do work (like if I add a link to bootstrap's minified CSS and add some class (like 'btn-primary' to some button on my HAML), everything works as I expect it to). Just the path to my own CSS doesn't.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title
            Title
        </title>
        <link type="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/main.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            ...
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a slash to your css path: `/css/main.css`. If you don't the path will be relative as seen in your posted generated page: `../public/css/main.css`. Since this is a call the browser does to your sinatra app it needs to be an absolute path. Sinatra is not serving any relative paths at all - would be a bit dangerous that..... By default sinatra is serving everything in the `public` directory as static files.